# Selecting text on WebKit2

Tags: vala

What method is available to select text on webkit2gtk. I could not find anything on the API for Vala webkit2:
https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-4.0/WebKit.WebView.html

The requirement is to get the selected text on a webpage after the user releases the mouse after text selection.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck with this question on Stack Overflow. Also, it's really more of a WebKit question than a Vala question, so don't forget the webkit and webkitgtk tags.

Comment: Many thanks, asked the question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442869/how-to-get-selected-text-on-webkit2gtk

Answer (score -1):

Based on the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442869/how-to-get-selected-text-on-webkit2gtk), I'm concluding that there is no direct way to interact with the DOM in WebKit2GTK. The work around is to use the following:

1. Run a javascript function using WebView.run_javascript
2. Within the javascript function, assign the result to document.title
3. Fetch the results back using the WebView.get_title()

Seems a bit roundabout way, but it works.